# Determine if datepicker is open

Tags: c#, datepicker, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm developing a Windows Store App and I'm trying to determine when the datepicker control is in open state (user can select a option from the list), but i can't find a option to determine this state of the control.

When using the ComboBox there is a property `ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen`, but there is no equivalent in the DatePicker or the TimePicker control.

Does anyone know how i could achieve the same on a datepicker control?

Comment: the `DatePicker.CalendarOpened` event? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.calendaropened(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm developing a Windows Store App (did not state this clearly). But there is no CalendarOpened event.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/apps/dn298584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the DatePicker -> Edit Template -> Edit a Copy
2. Add a handler for DropDownOpened event for each ComboBox in the template